# Azure DevOps Pipelines HelmDeploy: how to get latest version on chartPath

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I have an Azure Pipeline that builds a Docker container and uploads it to Azure Container Registry.

The source code chart is packaged, deployed on the temp artifact path, and then deployed to Kubernetes with Helm 3 commands.

```
   - task: HelmDeploy@0
        inputs:
          command: 'package'
          chartPath: Server/charts/server
          destination: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

      - task: HelmDeploy@0
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
          kubernetesServiceConnection: 'Staging12602128'
          namespace: 'staging'
          command: 'upgrade'
          chartType: 'FilePath'
          chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/server-0.0.1.tgz' <<== How to select latest version?
          releaseName: 'server'
```

The destination on the package command, uses the latest version of the chart, and it's like this /home/vsts/work/1/a/server-0.1.1.tgz

The chartPath of the upgrade command, in all the examples, needs the exact version of the tgz package.
How do I automatically insert the latest chart version in the "chartPath" in the upgrade task so I don't have to change it manually on every upgrade?

I tried without success:

```
 chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/server-*.tgz'
 chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.tgz'
 chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.SourceVersion).tgz'
 chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/server-$(Build.DefinitionName).tgz'
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @FrancesoCristallo can you consider upvoting my reply it it were helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your version number comes from, but even without that you can try thich approach:

```yaml
- task: HelmDeploy@0
    inputs:
      command: 'package'
      chartPath: Server/charts/server
      destination: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
- pwsh: |
        $charts = Get-ChildItem
        $sorted = $charts | sort -Descending
        $latest = $sorted[0]
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=chartName;]$latest"
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: HelmDeploy@0
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
      kubernetesServiceConnection: 'Staging12602128'
      namespace: 'staging'
      command: 'upgrade'
      chartType: 'FilePath'
      chartPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(chartName)' <<== How to select latest version?
      releaseName: 'server'
```